# How can I get rid of the login prompt for users denied access to site through IIS?

Tags: iis, windows-authentication

Users denied access to my website get a login prompt.  I do not want to give them a login prompt, I just want them to get an error message.  How do I bypass the login prompt?

I have a static html website hosted on Windows Server 2016.  The site is being served through IIS 10.  Users will be accessing the site from their own browsers.   **I need to control access through folder permissions, and not through Windows Authorization**.  So I have Windows Authentication enabled through IIS, but not Windows Authorization.  Windows authentication is enabled so that the user account associated with the computer used to access the site is stored.  Users who have access to the proper folders and file can access the site just fine.  However, users who have been denied access to the proper folders get a login prompt.  I want to bypass the login prompt and just give them an error message.  Does anyone know why I am getting the login prompt?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the login prompt is controled by the browser, we couldn't modify it through the IIS.

The only way to avoid showing the login prompt is using IE. IE's securty setting contains the setting "Automatic logon only in intranet zone".

[image]

More details, you could refer to below article:

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/8442/how-to-make-the-windows-authentication-login-prompts-for-user-credentials-in-browsers